# Assignment of protected attribute for email confirmation rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, protected

There are several questions that address very similar issues, but either I am misunderstanding the solutions or some nuance in the questioner's situation.

The attribute `confirmed` is protected, and thus I cannot mass assign it.  After researching it, it seems like the following solution should work.  I am able to view both the `token` (also protected) and the `confirmed` in the flash, but I am not able to set `confirmed' below that.  What am I doing wrong?

```
  if !@user.confirmed && params[:token] == @user.token
    flash[:success] = @user.token, @user.confirmed
    @user.confirmed = true
    @user.save
  end
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replicated your scenario in one of my test apps and I am able to set published (in your case confirmed) to true.

**Migration**

```
def up
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.boolean :published, :default => false
      t.string :token
      t.timestamps
end
```

**Model**

```
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_protected :published

  before_create :generate_token

  def generate_token
    self.token = Time.now().to_i
  end

end
```

**Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def publish
    @post = Post.find_by_token(params[:token])
    if !@post.published && params[:token] == @post.token # The second condition is not necessary in this case.
      @post.published = true
      @post.save
    end
  end
end
```

**Creating the DB record form console**

```
1.9.3-p0-perf :001 > p = Post.new({:title => "Protests against Violence"})
 => #<Post id: nil, title: "Protests against Violence", published: false, token: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
1.9.3-p0-perf :002 > p.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (7.3ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("created_at", "published", "title", "token", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Thu, 14 Feb 2013 07:41:58 UTC +00:00], ["published", false], ["title", "Protests against Violence"], ["token", 1360827718], ["updated_at", Thu, 14 Feb 2013 07:41:58 UTC +00:00]]
   (7.5ms)  COMMIT
 => true 
1.9.3-p0-perf :003 > p.reload
  Post Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
 => #<Post id: 2, title: "Protests against Violence", published: false, token: "1360827718", created_at: "2013-02-14 07:41:58", updated_at: "2013-02-14 07:41:58">
```

After hitting the /publish/1360827718 - here is the output from the console

```
#<Post id: 2, title: "Protests against Violence", published: true, token: "1360827718", created_at: "2013-02-14 07:41:58", updated_at: "2013-02-14 07:45:33">
```

I am running this code with postgresql, rails 3.2.11 and ruby 1.9.3 and the publish action in the controller sets the published=true

Sometimes comparing the code that works with the one that doesn't helps identify the problem and that's the intention behind this answer.

Hope this helps you to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add these attributes to attr_accessible in your models.

And read this for detailed information:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I don't want `confirmed` to be accessible in that way--I would like it to be a protected attribute.

Comment: Otherwise you won't be able to change it, unless with direct database request